# groovy/XML: Replace a node by another one

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

I try to replace an XML node by another one by using `XmlSlurper` (or `XmlParser`).

The original XML:

```
<myXml>
  ...
  <myNode>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Name>name3</Name>
 </myNode>
 ...
</myXml>
```

The list that contains the items to build my new node

```
def namelist = ['name4','name5','name6','name7']
```

What I want to have

```
<myXml>
  ...
  <myNode>
    <Name>name4</Name>
    <Name>name5</Name>
    <Name>name6</Name>
    <Name>name7</Name>
 </myNode>
 ...
</myXml>
```

To remove the node I tried this but the node is still present:

```
def myXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
myXml.myNode[0].replaceNode {}
```

Then I didn't find a solution to create the new node by using a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = '''<myXml>
  <myNode>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Name>name3</Name>
 </myNode>
</myXml>'''
def namelist = ['name4','name5','name6','name7']
def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

slurped.myNode.replaceNode {
 myNode {
    namelist.collect { n ->
      Name "$n"
    }
 }
}

new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    mkp.yield slurped
}.toString()
```

The node was in fact replaced but you need to serialize XML to see it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't serialize the XML that's why I didn't see any update. Thanks